# C# client requesting data from python web service using bottle.py

Tags: c#, python

The bottle web service is not able to accept any data to process, and am not able to figure out what the problem is.
Am suspecting that the route statement and the corresponding def statement is not correct and I cant find an example online.

It returns:The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.)
I need some help to figure this out.

Here is the client code making the call.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
       {"MemberOid", "564d783b54355e2070173117"},
       {"ConnectionName", "mongodb://100.19.6.122"},
       {"DBName", "NATHANDB"}
    };
    var dataString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:8080/" + "getData", "POST", dataString);
}
```

Here is the section of the web service, with the route statement and def statements.

```
@route('/getData', method='POST')
def getScore(updatedata):
    data = request.body.readline()
    ...
    ...
```

any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your web service engine, but a 500 error means a server error, not a missing resource. If you change your c# code to request a bogus route, like `"http://localhost:8080/" + "bogusRoute"`, do you still get the same 500 error?

Comment: am getting this Error: 404 Not Found